# How do i switch the text at a delimiter in a line?

Tags: windows, notepad++

I'm struggling to solve this problem in Notepad++. I'd really appreciate a good answer.

Let's say I have this line:

```
watermelon:strawberries
```

And I want to get this:

```
strawberries:watermelon
```

How can I do this for all lines in Notepad++? I've tried different kind of things but I couldn't get this result.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have `some string`, followed by a `:` followed by `some string`, and you want both some string's to swap places, you can use a RegEx search and replace to make them change position.

Open a Search and Replace dialog (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)

In the Find what: enter `(.+):(.+)`

In the Replace With: enter `\2:\1`

At the bottom at Search Mode, change it to Regular expression.

Hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd> and all will be swapped.

If this does not give you the desired result, please edit your question and better specify what you want. Its a bit open to interpretation now, so I assume a whole row where somewhere there is a : and it will swap things. There can be multiple words with spaces etc, and all will swap with it.

---

## The regex explained:

`(` ... `)` is a group. Whenever you add a group in regex, in the replace you can retrieve what it found using \1, \2, \3 in order of entered.
`.` is: find any character.
`+` is: previous one or more times.

So `(.+)` means, Create a group that we can find and in this group find any character one or more times.

`:` is: This character has no meaning, so it is being search for as a literal `:`.
And again the `(.+)` as explained above.

So in laymans terms, we find anything until we find a `:` and place it in a group, and whatever remains, we place in another group. These are groups 1 and 2 repsectively.

In our replace with, we swap the positions of the group by first referring to group 2 and then 1, and we add the `:` to separate the groups again.

Comment: Note: this pattern will not trigger on lines where there is nothing before or after the colon. Use (.*):(.*) i.e. * instead of + to trigger on "0 or more occurrences of [any character]" (which is what * does) instead of "1 or more occurrences of [any character]" (which is what + does).

Comment: @SadBunny yes, that is by design. Why would you want to swap if there is nothing to swap?

Comment: Well, hustler225 might want to swap
blah:   (or :blah)
to
:blah   (or blah:)
... or he may not. Your pattern doesn't, but as the requirement wasn't that specific, I thought I'd just add that note.

Comment: Yeah, I understand where you're coming from @SadBunny. Just specified why I chose the + over * so that people are not downvoting me because they think I made an error. I did it with a reason. :)

Comment: Well, your "we find anything until we find a : " is also incorrect if you don't specify the pattern as non-greedy by adding a ?.

Comment: @SadBunny Notepad++ is non-greedy by default. I tested this with a large string and added somewhere a : and it worked well. Only if there are 2 or more : in the same string things go wrong, but I specified that I'm searching for only one, and if this is not correct, the question should be altered.

Comment: Notepad is non-greedy by default? Where's that coming from? Can't reproduce. Replacing (.+):(.+) by $2:$1 for "x:y:z" gives me "z:x:y".

Comment: Also, nothing goes wrong, it's both perfectly valid, the question is what is actually required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44271/discussion-between-lpchip-and-sadbunny).

Answer (score 0):

1. Press CTRL-H for search/replace function.
2. Activate "Regular expression mode" (alt-g or radio button on the lower left)
3. Enter the following regular expression find pattern in the "Find what" input: **(.*):(.*)**
4. Enter the following regular expression replace pattern in the "Replace with" input: **$2:$1**
5. Use the buttons on the top right to loop through the found results or use "Replace All" to replace them all in one go.

Couple of notes:

- You may want to revise the pattern if some of your lines contain multiple colons.
- You may want to learn more about regular expressions. Check pages like http://www.regular-expressions.info/ or the comprehensive https://regex101.com/ (or use Google - it's a big big topic)